# I can over, I can out - What am i?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

What is in tongue also in tree,

Rivers, roads scattered about,

Tuning for a perfect pitch,

I can over, I can out.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer of this riddle is

> a Fork

Comment: Please keep your answer in spoiler tags.

Comment: Correct.  It's an easy one but would still be nice to see some explanations.